# What does non magnetic and nonconducting mean in reflection and transmission of waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, reflection, refraction

So, we were ask to consider the Fresnel Equations for parallel and perpendicular waves (with index of refractions).

Then, we are ask to prove some equations in which "... for nonmagnetic non-conductors"

The Fresnel equations got reduced and the indexes of refraction disappeared. I do not really know where to start, but in our reference book we have: normal incidence and oblique incidence topics.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simplification. Typically, you use boundary conditions to relate the fields outside and inside the dielectric that say that the normal component of the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ has a discontinuity so that the auxiliary field $\mathbf{D}$ is continuous. There is also another condition that says that the tangential component of $\mathbf{E}$ is continuous across the boundary. Since $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$, I don't think this continues to be the case if $\mathbf{B}$ has a discontinuity, as will be the case in a magnetic material. In a magnetic material, the $\mathbf{B}$-field jumps at the boundary owing to an induced surface current density. Look at Jackson or Griffiths for details on these boundary conditions.

Similarly, the material being non-conducting means that you don't have to worry about things like a current-density $\mathbf{J} = \sigma \mathbf{E}$ being induced by the electric field. However, I have a suspicion that the non-conducting requirement is not really necessary, since you can incorporate the conductivity $\sigma$ into the electrical permittivity (look up, for example, the Drude model in Jackson).